# Calculating distance with google maps api and set it in a table <td>

Tags: javascript, routes, distance

I'm trying to calculate the distance using geolocation and google maps routes, i already calculate the distance, but i need to show the distance in a . I'm trying to do it with document.write but it doesn't work, can somebody help me? thanks!

sorry for my english, it is not my antive language.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var myPos;
    var marker;
    var tDist = 0;
    var directionsRenderer;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoOK, geoKO);
    } else {
       geoMaxmind();
    }


    function geoOK(position) {
        showMap(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    }


    function geoMaxmind() {
        showMap(geoip_latitude(), geoip_longitude());
    }

    function geoKO(err) {
        if (err.code == 1) {
            error('El usuario ha denegado el permiso para obtener información de ubicación.');
        } else if (err.code == 2) {
            error('Tu ubicación no se puede determinar.');
        } else if (err.code == 3) {
            error('TimeOut.')
        } else {
            error('Oops!, algo malo pasó.');
        }
    }

    function showMap(lat, longi) {

    myPos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,longi);

    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: myPos,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), myOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myPos,
        title:"your position",
        draggable:false,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    marker.setMap(map);

    directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
        travelToAddress();
    }

    function travelToAddress(){

      //Obtenemos la direccion
      var origen=marker.getPosition();

      destino=document.forms[0].address.value;
      directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      // opciones de busqueda
      var request = {
        origin: origen,
        destination: destino,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request,getRuta);
    }

    function getRuta(result, status){

        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

        var nlegs = result.routes[0].legs.length;
           for (var i = 0; i < nlegs; i++) {
           tDist += result.routes[0].legs[i].distance.value;
           }
           directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
           alert("Distance:"+tDist);
        } else {
           error("Ha ocurrido un error debido a : " + status);
        }
    }


    function error(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
</script>undefined</head>undefined<body>
<div class="contenedor">
    <header></header>
    <main>
        <div class="tabRes">
            <table border=2 class='table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive' cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <b>Name</b>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <b>Distance</b>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <b>something</b>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <b>Something else</b>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $conexion = new buscar(__HOST__,__USUARIODB__,__PASSDB__,__DATABASE__);
                    $datos=$conexion->showD($_GET['buscar']);
                    if ($datos != false) {
                    while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)){
                    ?>
                    <form>
                        <input id="destino" type="text" name="address" value="
                            <?php echo $fila['Address']; ?>" />
                        </form>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $fila['Name']; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <script type="text/javascript">document.write(tDist);</script>
                            </td>
                            <?php echo"
                            <td>
                                <a href='some.php?something=".$fila['ID']."&check=".$_GET['check']."'>
                                    <button class='btn btn-primary'>to Something</button>
                                </a>
                            </td>"; ?>
                            <?php echo "
                            <td>
                                <a href='where.php?something=".$fila['ID']."&check=".$_GET['check']."'>
                                    <button id='check' class='btn btn-warning'>where to go</button>
                                </a>
                            </td>"; ?>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                     }
                } else {
                        echo "a message";
                    }
                ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- fin de tabRes -->
        </main>
    </body>
```

Comment: jsfiddle please...

Comment: Where do you want to show the message exactly?

Comment: @ParagBhayani after the form, there is a <td> and a <script>, i try with document.write but it is show me "0"

Comment: Okay the reason is you are writing the location on the serverside and you are finding the location on the client side, so it will not work.

Client side code execution starts only after your page is generated and returned from the server so tDist variable won't be available for you there ...

Comment: I don't have your database so I am not getting what php variable will contain it's value, would you show me your dummy HTML page, where database values are filled up

Comment: now i have another problem, how can i calculate the distance if the search show two results? it just show the first result but the second doesn't

Comment: If this answer was useful then upvote and accept

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting correct distance in this function

Changes in your HTML (create a span element with id):

```
<td>
   <span id='distance'></span></script>
</td>
```

Changes in your Javascript code(update result in the span):

```
function getRuta(result, status){

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

    var nlegs = result.routes[0].legs.length;
       for (var i = 0; i < nlegs; i++) {
       tDist += result.routes[0].legs[i].distance.value;
       }
       directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
       alert("Distance:"+tDist);
       // Here you get element from the table and append the distance here
       document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML = tDist;
    } else {
       error("Ha ocurrido un error debido a : " + status);
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Here I have assumed that you have single element only to show distance in the result, but if you want to show the list of result then assign id to the span in sequence and also update them in the sequence.

Here you need to follow below steps

1) Create lists of spans with unique id in your php code i.e.

```
<td>
   <span id='distance' .$fila['ID'] ></span></script>
</td>
```

Note: In above example you can have another unique id variable aswell(which changes for every row), of your choice

2) So now on client side every span has different element ids like 'distance101', 'distance102'

3) Now loop through your data and find distance using your -getRuta- function

4) When you get it's response get it's relevant span element from the page and set distance value in it

```
document.getElementById("distance"+uniqueIdentfier).innerHTML = tDist;
```

Comment: thanks man :) but i can't show the distance for the list yet, it show me the same first distance again.

Comment: That is what I mentioned in the note, you need to create array of elements in HTML and use loop over them to find correct element, Here you must have differenet element ids for each created elements

Comment: I think I don't got it, It is not working yet, maybe because I don0t understand how to add html elements in a array

Comment: I will be away from my px for 2 days meanwhile you try and if not succeed create fiddle will see it on Monday

Comment: can you help me with the loop showing the distance?

Comment: @kev  I have updated answer to guide you how you can achieve this ... follow the steps and you will achieve what you want

Comment: i'm doing like this <?php echo "<td><span id='distance".$fila['ID']."'></span></td>" ?> and then in the javascript i didn't got it how to set it the uniqueIdentfier, have I create a new var?

Comment: At client side how you get those server data? Do you get that result in some variable?

Comment: like this? <?php echo "<td><span id='distance".$fila['ID']."'></span></td>" ?> 
<script>id=<?php echo $fila['ID']; ?></script> 

and then I add var id to distance in the javascript, like this: document.getElementById("distance"+id).innerHTML = tDist;

Comment: i did that but it just show me the second distance result

Comment: I can't see any loop in javascript in the fiddle, and I don't know which object contains locations information, there must be an object on client side, which will hold the location information, using which we can find distance between 2 locations ... So with such data please update fiddle

Comment: there is an input id="destino" who had the first location and myPos is the second location and is set by the geolocation @paragbhayani

Comment: So these are the 2 locations, then there could only be one distance between those 2 locations, right? Then what do you need dynamic in your code? It will have one source and one destination and one distance...